# I need to zip all files and subdirectories in a folder including those that start with a dot

Tags: zip

I need to zip all files and subdirectories in a folder including those that start with a `.` (dot).

I'm in a folder called `synthesis` and I need to zip all the files and subdirectories under it (but not the `synthesis` folder itself).  The `synthesis` folder includes a subdirectory called `.sopc_builder` that has a file in it.

I tried the following command

```
zip -r synthesis.zip *
```

I copied the resulting `synthesis.zip` to another folder and listed the zip contents in a file:

```
unzip -l synthesis.zip > filelist.txt
```

The `filelist.txt` doesn't have the `.sopc_builder` and its file in the list.

I saw on some post something about a Linux command `shopt`, but didn't really understand it.

The version of Linux I'm using is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.9 at my company.

Thanks in advance,
Grady

Answer (score 2):

That should just be:

```
zip -r file.zip ./
```

The trailing `/` is apparently needed to work around a bug whereby if there was a file called `-` in the current directory, it would be treated as stdin.

To include hidden files in a glob (but not `.` nor `..`), you can use `zsh` and use the `*(D)` glob (the `D` for `dotglob` glob qualifier), but <strike>`zip -r file.zip *(D)`</strike> like <strike>`zip -r file.zip *`</strike> would be wrong on several grounds:

- it would fail if file names started with `-`. `--` would help, but not for a file called `-`. `./*(D)` would be better.
- `zip` by default treats its argument as wildcards (it's more of a MS-DOS type of program). So if any of the file names contain wildcard characters, especially `[...]`, that could cause errors. Use `-nw` to disable that, which you'll want to use anytime you pass arbitrary file names.

```
$ ls -AR
.:
'*'   ...          bar    fifo|      .foo   -h     '[x]'
 -   'a'$'\n''b'   dir/   file.zip   foo    link@

./dir:
-
$ rm -f file.zip; zip -r file.zip ./
        zip warning: ignoring FIFO (Named Pipe) - use -FI to read: ./link
        zip warning: ignoring FIFO (Named Pipe) - use -FI to read: ./fifo
  adding: bar (stored 0%)
  adding: [x] (stored 0%)
  adding: ... (stored 0%)
  adding: .foo (stored 0%)
  adding: a^Jb (stored 0%)
  adding: * (stored 0%)
  adding: - (stored 0%)
  adding: foo (stored 0%)
  adding: dir/ (stored 0%)
  adding: dir/- (stored 0%)
  adding: -h (stored 0%)
$ rm -f file.zip; zip -nw -r file.zip ./*(D)
        zip warning: ignoring FIFO (Named Pipe) - use -FI to read: ./fifo
        zip warning: ignoring FIFO (Named Pipe) - use -FI to read: ./link
  adding: * (stored 0%)
  adding: - (stored 0%)
  adding: ... (stored 0%)
  adding: a^Jb (stored 0%)
  adding: bar (stored 0%)
  adding: dir/ (stored 0%)
  adding: dir/- (stored 0%)
  adding: .foo (stored 0%)
  adding: foo (stored 0%)
  adding: -h (stored 0%)
  adding: [x] (stored 0%)
```

See how symlinks and fifos are handled by default. The `zip` format is more one to use when you want to pack files to be used on other OSes like Microsoft Windows. To create archive of Unix files, you'd rather use `tar`.

Comment: Great! The manual doesn't mention the trailing slash.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity, not, but that should not be needed. It's just to work around that bug which I just found out. They would rather fix the bug than document the work around.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to combine `zip` with `find`:

```bsh
$ cd the/dir/you/want/to/zip
$ find . -print | zip test -@
adding: file.txt (stored 0%)
adding: .hidden/ (stored 0%)
adding: .hidden/file2.txt (stored 0%)
```

[According to the manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip)

```
-@ file lists. If a file list is specified as -@ [Not on MacOS],
zip takes the list of input files from standard input instead
of from the command line. For example,
    zip -@ foo 
will store the files listed one per line on stdin in foo.zip.

Under Unix, this option can be used to powerful effect
in conjunction with the find (1) command.
For example, to archive all the C source files in the current directory
and its subdirectories:
    find . -name "*.[ch]" -print | zip source -@ 
(note that the pattern must be quoted to keep the shell from expanding it).
```